# Writing python script to select attributes not in growing table with over 4000 values?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I am trying to write a **Python script** that will automate the process of comparing files within a directory to the id of a feature class, and then create (or refresh) a layer with only the features that do not find a file within the directory with their id.

I have created a Python script that almost successfully does this (works with test data) but **my problem** seems to be that the directory it is looking at contains over 4000 files (which appears to be **SELECT BY ATTRIBUTE**'s limit) and will continue to grow in size.

Here is an example of the script I am trying to use:

```
import arcpy
import os

jpg = os.listdir(directory location)
photos =([s.strip('.jpg') for s in jpg])

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(feature class location ,r"in_memory/headphotos")

tmp_layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("in_memory/headphotos")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=tmp_layer,selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause=' "ce_id" NOT IN' + str(tuple(photos)))

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(tmp_layer,new layer)
```

You will notice that I use **str(tuple(*directory reference*)** as my current mode of cycling through the list of 4000+ files.

Is there a way to get past the problem of SELECT BY ATTRIBUTE only managing to contain some not all of the files?

Is there a way that I could possibly be doing this more efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried in the other direction - use a search cursor to go through the features, check if they're in the list, and if they're not write them out with an insert cursor?

Comment: `NOT IN` is heinously inefficient with only a handful of members; using it with thousands is just not viable. If I were using a SQL database I'd do an OUTER JOIN. Don't forget about the ability to add selection elements and flip the selection set at the end.

Comment: As you're creating a temp feature class you could add a field (found?) and update cursor through the features setting found to 1 where the file is in the list and found to 0 where not in the list then all you need to do is select where found = 0. As you are comparing strings it's a good idea to either upper() or lower() both strings as python is a case sensitive language.

Comment: Sorry I don't have years of experience when it comes to this kind of thing - hence why I'm the one always asking questions!  I have just tried to read up on search and update cursors but I don't quite understand any examples they have shown.  Can someone show me a basic example of what this would look like 'searching layer A for a similar value in table B, then populate a new field with that value'. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comment I made:

```
import os, sys, arcpy

# A different way of getting a list of raster files, I find this one better
# as os.listdir returns *everything* and you need to sort out the junk.
arcpy.env.workspace = 'directory location'
jpgList = arcpy.ListRasters('*','JPG') # List only JPEG images in the *workspace*

photos =([s.lower().strip('.jpg') for s in jpgList ]) # do all comparison in lower case

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(feature class location ,r"in_memory/headphotos")
arcpy.AddField_management("in_memory/headphotos",'Located','SHORT') # Add the 'Located' field

# using an update cursor mark every row to indicate if the photo is located
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("in_memory/headphotos",['ce_id','Located']) as UCur:
    for URow in UCur:
        if URow[0].lower() in photos: # if 'ce_id' in lower case is found in photos
            URow[1] = 1               # set 'Located' to 1 (Yes)
        else:
            URow[1] = 0               # otherwise set 'Located' to 0 (No)
        UCur.updateRow(URow)          # Save the change for this row

# Using a where clause to limit to only unfound rows
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("in_memory/headphotos",'tmp_layer','Located = 0')
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('tmp_layer',new layer)
```

I hope this brings you to a better understanding of using cursors in arcpy. Please note the `with` statement, this is possibly universally agreed to be the best way to handle `arcpy.da` cursors; do not confuse with `arcpy` cursors (not da) which are incompatible with `with` statements. This is because cursors, of either type, *must* be deleted to release locks on datasets which can cause *real* headaches.

Comment: small typo - for in s in *jpgList*

Comment: Perhaps skip update row , i.e. remove else

Comment: Well spotted @MarcPfister. I've fixed that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will now be able to use this in the future as well.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I have just tried to add a second update cursor to the same script as the above example that will change the 'Located' field to 1 if another field has a similar name ... using a LIKE statement in the Where clause.  I seem to have issues with the like.                              
                                                                                                               with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("in_memory/headphotos",['surname','Located']) as UCur1:
    for URow in UCur1:
        if (URow[0].lower() LIKE '%reserve%'):
            URow[1] = 1

Comment: It would be best to ask a new question and reference this thread for background. I suspect your problem is because you have two active update cursors on the same layer which causes a lock situation but can't be 100% sure without seeing all the code.

Comment: Thanks, I've created a second question if you are interested in looking into it.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254890/how-to-use-a-like-clause-in-an-update-cursor-syntax-error