# Using LIKE in a For Loop with UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5, for-loop

I have a classified raster with a class value that is a very long concatenated string name (Class_Name below). I'm trying to use arcpy to generate integer labels ranging from 1-24 (which are the third concatenated sub-group in these long strings). Here's an example of a previous (manually manipulated) similar raster attribute table.
[image]

So far I've been manually using search criteria in ERDAS to find classes belonging to the same group such as:

$"Class_Names" contains "-14.01-" or $"Class_Names" contains "-14.02-" or $"Class_Names" contains "-14.03-"

I've tried using the following code (as a trial for the first two classes) with LIKE in a for loop with UpdateCursor, but I get a syntax error for my LIKE statement.

```
in_table = 'l12wm_agsup02.img'
field_names = ['Class_Name', 'crop']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table, field_names) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] 'LIKE \'1.%\'':
            row[1] = 1
        elif row[0] 'LIKE \'2.%\'':
            row[1] = 2
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I've looked at [Using LIKE clause in update cursor gives syntax error?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254890/using-like-clause-in-update-cursor-gives-syntax-error) and https://community.esri.com/thread/87848 but can't figure out how to use LIKE in the if else statements instead as a where clause in UpdateCursor.

I'm using ArcMap 10.5, Python 2.7

Comment: You've missed out an important bit of information, what is the actual error message?

Comment: It highlights the last single quote in if row[0] 'LIKE \'1.%\ ' ':

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error message rather than a logic problem?

Comment: regular expression can be used for mimmicking LIKE (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148712/compare-strings-in-python-like-the-sql-like-with-and) but in your case @Aaron 's solution is the most straightforward (!Class_Name!.split("-")[2].split(".")[0] can also be applied in the field calculator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would isolate the class you are after rather than searching for it. Then, simply assign `row[1]` that isolated value. For example:

```
in_table = 'l12wm_agsup02.img'
field_names = ['Class_Name', 'crop']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table, field_names) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0].split("-")[2].split(".")[0]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron, that worked like a charm! I forgot to mention that for some rows, 'Class_Name' was empty and one row would always be 'Unclassified'. I received an error something along the lines of "Index out of range" and so I added an if/elif/else to leave these as they were.

Answer (score 2):

This does not have to be done in a python script, it can be done simpler by using the calculate field tool as shown below:

[image: Tool]

If you want to run this as python the code would be:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("myRaster","crop","cropnumber( !class! )","PYTHON_9.3","""def cropnumber(s):/n  if s.find("-1.") != -1:/n    return 1/n  elif s.find("-2.") != -1 :/n    return 2/n  else:/n    return -999""")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details), for example:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table, field_names) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if '1.' in row[0]:
            row[1] = 1
...
```

And instead of writing 24 if statements you can use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
d = {'1.':1, '2.':2, '3.':3} #add all values here

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table, field_names) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for key in d:
            if key in row[0]:
                row[1]=d[row[0]]
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```

But this wont work since '2.' is in both '12.' and '22.' so you can do:

```
row[1] = row[0].split('-')[2].split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. I ran your first block of code and replaced the second to last line with your second block of code. For some reason, it didn't generate a value for half of the records and I can't find a pattern. Those that worked: 2.0, 13.01, 13.06, 11.0, 11.5, and 11.0. Those that didn't: 4.05, 5.03, 14.03, 5.01, 6.0, 6.04, 6.02, 7.0, 6.05.

Comment: You need to add those to the dictionary. Use @Aarons answer instead

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your text based on dash (-) to split the text and select the 3rd number to convert it to integer. Try the following python code in your field calculator:

```
def select(f):
    if f == ' ':
        return 0
    else:
        txt = f.split("-")[2]
        digit = int(round(float(txt),0))
        return digit
```

The above code assumes all the column of Class_Name is filled with information with the same structure. If the field is empty of text, it will return zero (0). However, I used `round()` function to round the class to the nearest whole number in case you have something like `4.98`, it will return `5` instead of `4`. But, if you want to truncate the digit numbers, you can simply change the line:

```
digit = int(round(float(txt),0))
```

to:

```
digit = int(float(txt))
```

[image]

Here is  sample output:

[image]